# links in html document

Tags: html

There are two links in html document, which i want to open with in same page(not window) but one link content should appear at a time?

```
<body>

<a href="numbers.html"> Numbers</a>
<a href="data.html"> Data</a>


<div id="show"> </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense. I'd recommend editing your question to add some more detail.

Comment: Hi Sira, could you rephrase your question a little? I don't understand "one link content should appear at a time?"

Comment: @jim , i mean that if i click on 'numbers' link , the content of this link would appear under the link but when i click on 'data' link then just 'data' link content should appear and 'numbers' link content will be removed

Comment: Looks like a case for `iframe`s if you want to have content from one page embedded in another.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery it becomes as simple as using one method called `load`.. to make it elegant first add class to your links, e.g.

```
<a class="loader" href="numbers.html">Numbers</a>
<a class="loader" href="data.html">Data</a>
```

Then include jQuery and have such code to achieve what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loader").each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $("#show").load($(this).attr("href"));
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

This will load the HTML contents into the `show` div, replacing any previous contents.

Comment: @sira Just add this line to your existing code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` to include the latest jQuery hosted on Google servers. If you want, you can also copy that file to your own server and include it locally..

Comment: If you have doubt about Google read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn).

Answer (score 0):

what about you have an event on each link to switch between two divs, hide one and show the other. so it could be:

```
<div onclick="Show(numbers.html)"> Numbers</div>
<div  onclick="Show(data.html)"> Data</div>
```

and in Show() JS function you have and show the wanted div.

Comment: but as i have one div in which i want to open just one link content at a time not both at the same time ?? then what changes should be made in ur code

Comment: in the Show() function, you hide all divs and show one div (the div you send its id when you called the function(