# Google jQuery Reference no longer working with http

Tags: jquery

***EDIT: My problem is different than originally described.  This is actually specific to my computer and is affecting Chrome and Firefox, NOT IE.  I've rebooted and cleared cache and it still happens.  I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error on the http (I can directly open the file in my browser).  Weird.  Anyway, sorry to bother everyone...looks like I have a new problem to figure out.***

**EDIT 2: The problem was intermittent so hard to track down but turned out to be an issue with Avira Pro blocking the specific URL for Google for some reason.  Added to exception list and all is well again.**

I have several sites that use jQuery and jQuery UI.  I get the link from http://scriptsrc.net/ which simply copies a reference to your clipboard like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However as of 2 days ago I notice that this is no longer working for any site I have it on. It cannot find jQuery so all jQuery functions stopped working.

A quick fix is to chance the http to https and then it works.

Then I found this post:

> [Where do you include the jQuery library from? Google JSAPI? CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn)

Which is a bit different but it lead me to try to remove the http: or https: altogether and start with //.  But no dice there either.  Cannot find it.

So now I'm wondering:
1) Why did HTTP:// stop working?
2) What is the best way to reference jQuery at Google so that this doesn't happen again.

Thanks for your input

Comment: The HTTP link looks fine to me... try visit it in your browser and you get the jQuery file.

Answer (score 1):

The `http://` version still works on all my sites, and also when I navigate directly to it in Firefox.

If your sites are running under SSL it may be better for you to use a protocol independent link, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note - the lack of `http://` or `https://` at the start of the `src` url.