# Why isnt jQuery appearing in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my "good.html" and "jquery.js" file in a folder on desktop called "jquery2."

Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('ready');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you have this HTML file, and... what happens?

Comment: Your web browser isn't configured to allow scripts to run from your local filesystem.

Comment: Does jQuery have an appearance?

Answer (score 2):

Your

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`

is not referencing the file on your desktop.

In order to make this work, you should upload the files to a server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a server but you do need to use a good path to the javascript file on your desktop, on windows like so:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\username\Desktop\jquery2\jquery.js"></script>`

works for me on windows 7 with chrome browser. console shows ready.

If I make the path bad, console shows  "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" followed by a red X box next to
GET file:///C:/Users/wrongusername/Desktop/jquery2/jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

Its issue with your Javascript path... put on same folder of your code or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

more info
[Where do you include the jQuery library from? Google JSAPI? CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('ready');
        });
    </script>
```