# jQuery not working but Javascript will

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel really silly asking this, but it is completely blowing my mind why my link to the Google jQuery api isn't working. I know my code isn't broken because it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jefffabiny/8p46d/

Here are my script tags in my index file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

Other than that, the doctype is HTML5, and I'm working on an local xampp install. I bet I over looked something small; does anyone see the problem here? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Actually, after I submitted this post I got an alert at the top of my browser saying stack overflow requires javascript from an external domain to run properly, but it was being blocked. I guess that's my problem, but does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Looks like jQuery works fine to me

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: Do you see a JS error? If so, what's the error? Also, did you make sure to clear the cache?

Comment: look at your code in firefox sourcecode - are there red parts? If so  you've probably missed a quote or something like this

Comment: you can try an alert in your html inside jquery $().ready(function(){ alert('google api is working.');})

Comment: Did you check if the path of "functions.js" is correct? Can be a problem of relative/absolute path.

Comment: That edit is a real head-scratcher.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with it, but you should look at this anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn -> The jist of it it, forget the 'http:' and just us *"//ajax.googleapis..."*.

Comment: @Jack No there isn't an error, the jsfiddle code is copy and pasted from my js file

Comment: @islandmyth I tried that an no alert

Comment: @mathletics yes, yes it is lol

Comment: @phenomnomnominal yup, already tried it without the protocol. Still doesn't work.

Comment: And there's no errors or anything?

Comment: I wonder if the answer given is right: Perhaps throw in an alert($) before the function call, and see if jQuery is defined yet - it might not have loaded yet. Where in your HTML do you include the library?

Comment: there is a typo in my code if you copy pasted it you miss the semicolon `;` in the end

Comment: the edit, is like the pop-up in ie when including javascripts. Like you have to confirm to allow the files...

Comment: @islandmyth No it isn't a dialog box, it looks like a custom div stackoverflow created. I'm using chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you executing your code after DOM is ready? jsFiddle does!

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.test').on("click", function(){
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    });​
});
```

Comment: When nothing seems wrong, it's almost always `document.ready`.

Comment: I knew it would be something dumb... thank you. I'd still like to know if anyone has any input on that 'failed to load from another domain' alert.