# Changing the css of table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so on selection of a row it changes the color/background just like it does when I have it set to on hover and have the ability to deselect the row aswell...

If you check out: http://jsfiddle.net/q7ApN/ you can see what it's supposed to look like on hovering...

#### If Change:

```
#gradient-style tbody tr:hover td {
    background: #d0dafd url('table-images/gradhover.png') repeat-x;
    color: #339;
}
```

#### To

```
#gradient-style tbody tr:hover, tr.selected td {
    background: #d0dafd url('table-images/gradhover.png') repeat-x;
    color: #339;
}
```

#### Actual HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url("nstyle.css");
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
</script>
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="http://test.com/" target="_blank">test</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <table id="gradient-style" summary="">
        <tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">title</th>
                    <th scope="col">title</th>
                    <th scope="col">title</th>
                    <th scope="col">title</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tr><td>data</td><td class="test">data</td><td class="test">data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td class="test">data</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="test">data</td><td class="test">data</td><td class="test">data</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="test">data</td><td class="test">data</td><td class="test">data</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=34><em>testing box :)</em></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="footer_container">
    <div id="footer">
        <a href="http://test.com/" target="_blank">test</a>
        <div id="footer1">
            <i>test.</i>
        </div>
        <div id="footer2">
            <i>test test test.</i>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I already have the hover function, I'm trying to get a select function to work with the hover function, see the jsfiddle code

Comment: If you want change background/color on selected elements, just try `#gradient-style tbody tr:hover td, #gradient-style tr.selected td` instead `#gradient-style tbody tr:hover, tr.selected td`. See example http://jsfiddle.net/q7ApN/2/

Comment: Background doesn't apply on selected elements because `#gradient-style td` has more weight than `tr.selected td`.

Comment: @AleksDorohovich I tried merging your code from your jsfiddle with my code but unfortunately I can't get it to work how your js does... is my importing of the jquery correct? (I have a version downloaded into the same folder)

Comment: It's not js problem, just css. For selected elements just try to add css selector that has weight more than `#gradient-style td`. ID always has more "weight" than class. So, if you want change background color (or other property), then instead `tr.selected td` you should use `#gradient-style tr.selected td`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a js problem as I have copy and pasted the exact html, css and code into my script and it doesn't work. I even tried the 3 imports from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332697/whats-the-best-way-to-load-jquery

Comment: your updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q7ApN/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want.  Toggle the `selected` class on the `tr` when you click on a row, and also remove the selected class if you click on a sibling row.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("tr").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
    });
});
```

Then change the styles accordingly, as others have mentioned previously by using:

```
#gradient-style tbody tr:hover td,
#gradient-style tbody tr.selected td {
    background: #d0dafd url('table-images/gradhover.png') repeat-x;
    color: #339;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/q7ApN/8/

Comment: That works lovely, however I still can't merge this into my code the function does nothing in my sheets (I think it's to do with the jquery importing)

Comment: Your jquery is local.  My sound silly, but is the path correct?

Comment: I even followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332697/whats-the-best-way-to-load-jquery but It's still not seeminly using jquery?

Comment: Oh need to use `$(document).ready( function() {` first.  See my edit.  I just tried locally using `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` as my reference to jquery and it worked

Comment: Ahh, thank you ever so much that works perfectly. Green tick awarded and upboated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will works

Change this in CSS

```
#gradient-style tbody tr.selected td {
        background: #d0dafd url('table-images/gradhover.png') repeat-x;
        color: #339;
    }
```

Script

```
$("#gradient-style tr").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7ApN/9/)

Comment: Thanks for replying, however that doesn't seem to do anything different from the code I initially supplied.

Answer (score 1):

please check the following link http://jsfiddle.net/q7ApN/3/

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");

});
```

Comment: Hi @sarath that unfortunately only half works, it's supposed to do the white background as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/q7ApN/7/

this is working fine

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");

});
```

you need to add !important for

```
 .selected td {
        background: #d0dafd url('table-images/gradhover.png') repeat-x !important;
        color: #339;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use !important.

Comment: In case you're interested, the CSS just needed to be more specific, to override the previous td styles.  The selector needed to be: `#gradient-style tr.selected td` which a number of comments mentioned.  Using JS to style is bad practice and not needed here.  The class had already been added using JS, which was correct.  Then it's down to CSS to style using that new class.

Comment: thanks for suggestion i am verymuch new to javascript and jquery