# How to configure jQuery script dependencies for JuiceUI?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, juice-ui

Just getting started with JuiceUI, using VS2012, .net40 and ASP.net.
I've been trying to get a basic example to work (the Draggable); looks like a lot of other people have had similar problems, i.e. [Can't get Juice UI to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873629/cant-get-juice-ui-to-work?rq=1)

I'm not sure if there has been a recent change to the JuiceUI, but I downloaded mine through the Package Manager Console for 2 packages, which I assume are the latest:

Install-Package JuiceUI
Install-Package AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined

The second package was to get the necessary DLLs to work with VS2012.

As my example, I added the following in my aspx file:

```
<juice:Draggable ID="Draggable1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button1" />
```

Control with Button1 id does exist. The web.config was configured automatically by the JuiceUI installer.

The JuiceUI package downloads dependencies for jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery.UI.Combined 1.9.2.
However, when I try to run the example and check the JavaScript console in Chrome, I get the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost:51569/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
http://localhost:51569/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.js
```

The error only appears when I have the Draggable element present - if I remove just that element, everything else is ok. Those script files were not downloaded into my scripts directory - I have later versions as specified above. I tried to use the ASP ScriptManager to point to my JS files, i.e.

```
 <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"/>
 <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined"  Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"
```

However, it still seems to be looking for the old versions. Is this a problem with the JuiceUI DLL, or is it something in my configuration which I can fix?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JuiceApp.cs file in source repository for an example of how to go about it, but you can override the script definitions in a Global.asax.cs file to point at the new versions of your scripts. That should resolve the issue.

You might also consider using a new fork named [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew)