# Where in a WebMatrix project should the jquery CDN reference be placed?

Tags: jquery, google-api, cdn, webmatrix

I see here: [Where do you include the jQuery library from? Google JSAPI? CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn) that this is a good way to include jQuery from a CDN (Google's):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As jQuery 2 was just released, I am planning on using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...and the latest jQueryUI, too:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Note: These snippets, which are identical to the "canonical answer" on Stack Overflow linked to above, are from google's jQuery CDN page: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui

Now my question is: Where in a WebMatrix project should the references to the CDN go? In 
Web.Config? _AppStart.cshtml? _SiteLayout.cshtml? Or...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _SiteLayout.cshtml would be the place:

```
. . .
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- May want to replace the above before deploying with:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
..and similar for jquery-ui -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>
. . .
```

Of course, need to download jquery-2.0.0.min.js from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js and place it in the project's Scripts folder.