# Asynchronous call issue

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am facing thread issue in my application follow are the summary of the issue

:                   root cause of the code

```
document.strikeoffForm.submit();
window.open('<%= baseURL %>/jsps/makeStrikeOffs/Print.jsp', "printStrikeoff");
```

its happening because of Asynchronous call. the issue is I am doing like this,

1. submitting form
2. opening new window to show the submitted value.

But some time before submiting a form the 2 action happened beacuse of Asynchronous call.

All I want is how can I order things as once first call is finished than only second call of window open should happen. Because of this issue the window doesn't get proper values.

I think the solution in Ajax but I am not aware how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All thanks for your all inputs. 
It may be the not proper way but for as of now its working fine so its good to me..
I given solution like this:

```
document.strikeoffForm.submit();           
<%  Thread.sleep(500)%>        
window.open('<%= baseURL %>/jsps/makeStrikeOffs/Print.jsp', "printStrikeoff");
```

Comment: sleep() in JSP (http) seems bad.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy with a little [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and a little bit of [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form). Try the code below:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pageToSubmitTo.jsp',
        data: {
            $("#idOfYourForm").serialize()
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            // this is where we append a loading image
        },
        success:function(data){
            // successful request; 
            window.open('jsps/makeStrikeOffs/Print.jsp', "printStrikeoff");
        },
        error:function(){
            // failed request; give feedback to user
        }
    });
```

For this to work you have to [include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn) the JQuery library to your code.