# How to make a health bar

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my own version of a pokemon game using very simple HTML and JavaScript.

So far, I have everything covered, except the health bar. How do I make an entity in my code, that will represent a bar, and when the opposing team selects a move, the health bar goes down?

Would I use a bunch of small div's?

Comment: How are you drawing things; using a canvas or just floating elements or ASCII? Your question is too vague to get an answer.

Comment: @JDong given the considered solution, I assume DHTML, not canvas. Also, it should be quite straightforward with canvas. But you are right - this should be clarified by the asker.

Comment: I also assume you are asking about the rendering part only? The internal model representation should be obvious and up to you.

Comment: @JDong, I'm quite new to programming, especially to this language, I just signed up for the class at my school, so I honestly have no idea what you are talking about. Sorry if I wasn't able to clarify enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend a HTML progress bar:

```
<progress id="health" value="100" max="100"></progress>
```

And when they lose/gain health, do run this Javascript code:

```
let health = document.getElementById("health")
health.value -= 10; //Or whatever you want to do with it.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks better than the bootstrap plugin down below.

Comment: For completeness, there is also [JQuery's progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) for older browsers. Note that you don't need to download anything to use JQuery. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn).

Comment: Love it! Perfect for what I was looking for is there any way to make it have circular borders?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Bootstrap's progress bar component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Do i have to download anything for this to work?

Comment: there's a download page.  You'll need the css + js files

Answer (score -1):

Im working on a game too using nodejs pure js and a lot of libraries i recommend you use a percentage as the bar will cover the content

Comment: simple answer might not be helpful. could you please post some example code?

Comment: Sure , you could add to a span as an ex:( <span id="health">100</span>% ) then simply start the action in js: <br> hp = document.getElementById("health").innerHTML; damage = hp - 15; document.getElementById("health").innerHTML = damage; That's simply how you would put damage into action using a 100 health points