# Redundant to let Microsoft and Google host jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, google-cdn, microsoft-cdn

I've seen some arguments for using a CDN or not and other arguments on who (Google,Microsoft, etc.) is the best for hosting jQuery.

My question: Is it redundant to have multiple entities host jQuery? (in case one goes down)

Or, as an example, is it better for Google to host it and you also have your own library to fall back on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do you include the jQuery library from? Google JSAPI? CDN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn)

Comment: *"Is it redundant to have multiple entities host jQuery?"* -- Yes, and that is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either one would be fine. In addition, it's good practice have your code fall-back to local (on your own server) copy of jQuery.

Comment: So would you recommend using <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>  and  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> or like you said just one or the other? I just want to know if using both would cause any speed issues.