# Filter with CLASS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class

I'm trying to make a filter on a table but it doesn't want to work at all.

This is what i have so far.

This must all run on the same page without external stuff (if it's possible)

**This is my Javascript part:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).load(function () {
   $('#SoortFilter').change(function () {
     $(".all-sc").hide();
     $("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
   });
 });

  $(document).load(function () {
   $('#OnderwerpFilter').change(function () {
     $(".all-oc").hide();
     $("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
   });
 });

  $(document).load(function () {
   $('#GraadFilter').change(function () {
     $(".all-gc").hide();
     $("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
   });
 });

</script>
```

**This is my HTML part:**

```
<div class="myTable">

<table><tr>

<td>Sorteer op soort:<br><select size="1" id="SoortFilter">
<option id="all-sc">Alles tonen</option>
<option id="SC1">Opwarming</option>
<option id="SC2">Oefening</option>
<option id="SC4">Andere</option>
</select></td>

<td>Sorteer op onderwerp:<br><select size="1" id="OnderwerpFilter">
<option id="all-oc">Alles tonen</option>
<option id="OC11">Voetenwerk algemeen</option>
<option id="OC21">Tactiek dubbel</option>
<option id="OC23">Wedstrijd analyse</option>
</select></td>

<td>Sorteer op graad:<br><select size="1" id="GraadFilter">
<option id="all-gc">Alles tonen</option>
<option id="GC2">Gemakkelijk</option>
<option id="GC3">Gemiddeld</option>
<option id="GC4">Moeilijk</option>
<option id="GC6">Variabel</option>
</select></td>

</tr></table>

</div>


<div class="myTable"><table id="myTable">

         <tr>
         <td>ID</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"><img src="wait.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Soort</td>
         <td>Onderwerp</td>
         <td>Graad</td>
         <td>Benaming</td>
         <td>URL</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC1 OC11 GC6">
         <td>4</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Opwarming</td>
         <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
         <td>Variabel</td>
         <td>Agility oefeningen</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67XP-AekUoA>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67XP-AekUoA</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC11 GC2">
         <td>8</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
         <td>Gemakkelijk</td>
         <td>Splitstep - fundamentals - Kyo groen</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NYVs9pQgGSZzhCQXg3dnFfYUE/edit?pref=2&pli=1>https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NYVs9pQgGSZzhCQXg3dnFfYUE/edit?pref=2&pli=1</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC11 GC3">
         <td>11</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
         <td>Gemiddeld</td>
         <td>Vertrek vanuit de basis</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNgt6P_RDLc>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNgt6P_RDLc</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC21 GC4">
         <td>23</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Tactiek dubbel</td>
         <td>Moeilijk</td>
         <td>Lee Bok - Positiespel dubbel</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMYbU08AOaw&feature=youtu.be>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMYbU08AOaw&feature=youtu.be</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC4 OC23 GC6">
         <td>14</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Andere</td>
         <td>Wedstrijd analyse</td>
         <td>Variabel</td>
         <td>Londen 2012 - Heren dubbel - halve finale</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKj4S9ig7c8>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKj4S9ig7c8</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC4 OC23 GC6">
         <td>15</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Andere</td>
         <td>Wedstrijd analyse</td>
         <td>Variabel</td>
         <td>Londen 2012 - Heren enkel - finale</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytjD4f_I0sc>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytjD4f_I0sc</td>
         </tr>


</table></div>

</div>
```

Comment: your links are wrong! I test your code! example: href=https://www.youtub... need "" href="https://www.youtub...."

Comment: it's not about the links,,   the links work perfectly... even without the " "  (my table is a result of a PHP + MSSQL echo)    i'm having trouble with the class filter

Comment: You should patch the link, they may be the root of some bug. `<a href="http://...">link</a>`

Comment: your html is wrong => javscript probably not work.. filter work separate or suport filter with two or three selects values eg: Opwarming and Gemakkelijk?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/kbkkg4mc/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418834/filter-with-class-and-javascript/35420575#35420575

Comment: YES YES YES    CUCHU   THANK YOU VERRY MUCH   Thats the exact answer i needed

Comment: nice!! please! check my answer or like jaja need points!

Comment: Good problem for solve!

Comment: @ThomasDutoit yes, that's exactly what I have in my answer...

Comment: i only have one problem left,   my first table row (header) disappears when i select a filter

Comment: @Blag  thanks but i didn't know how i had to connect it all with jquery library

Comment: @ThomasDutoit ok, take a look, I put how to JQuery and I display the header line of your table now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this option:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div class="myTable">

<table><tr>

<td>Sorteer op soort:<br><select size="1" id="SoortFilter">
<option id="all-sc">Alles tonen</option>
<option id="SC1">Opwarming</option>
<option id="SC2">Oefening</option>
<option id="SC4">Andere</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>Sorteer op onderwerp:<br><select size="1" id="OnderwerpFilter">
<option id="all-oc">Alles tonen</option>
<option id="OC11">Voetenwerk algemeen</option>
<option id="OC21">Tactiek dubbel</option>
<option id="OC23">Wedstrijd analyse</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>Sorteer op graad:<br><select size="1" id="GraadFilter">
<option id="all-gc">Alles tonen</option>
<option id="GC2">Gemakkelijk</option>
<option id="GC3">Gemiddeld</option>
<option id="GC4">Moeilijk</option>
<option id="GC6">Variabel</option>
</select>
</td>

</tr>
</table>

</div>


<div class="myTable">
<table id="myTable">

         <tr id="thead">
         <td>ID</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"><img src="wait.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Soort</td>
         <td>Onderwerp</td>
         <td>Graad</td>
         <td>Benaming</td>
         <td>URL</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC1 OC11 GC6">
         <td>4</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Opwarming</td>
         <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
         <td>Variabel</td>
         <td>Agility oefeningen</td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC11 GC2">
         <td>8</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
         <td>Gemakkelijk</td>
         <td>Splitstep - fundamentals - Kyo groen</td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC11 GC3">
         <td>11</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
         <td>Gemiddeld</td>
         <td>Vertrek vanuit de basis</td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC21 GC4">
         <td>23</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Tactiek dubbel</td>
         <td>Moeilijk</td>
         <td>Lee Bok - Positiespel dubbel</td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC4 OC23 GC6">
         <td>14</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Andere</td>
         <td>Wedstrijd analyse</td>
         <td>Variabel</td>
         <td>Londen 2012 - Heren dubbel - halve finale</td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC4 OC23 GC6">
         <td>15</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Andere</td>
         <td>Wedstrijd analyse</td>
         <td>Variabel</td>
         <td>Londen 2012 - Heren enkel - finale</td>
         <td></td>
         </tr>


</table></div>


<body>
</html>
```

and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#SoortFilter').change(function () {
     //$(".all-sc").hide();
     filter();
     //$("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
   });

   $('#GraadFilter').change(function () {
     filter();
     //$(".all-gc").hide();
     //$("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
   });

   $('#OnderwerpFilter').change(function () {
     filter();
     //$(".all-oc").hide();
     //$("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
   });

 });

 function filter () {
        one = $("#SoortFilter").find(":selected").attr("id");
    two = $("#OnderwerpFilter").find(":selected").attr("id");
    three = $("#GraadFilter").find(":selected").attr("id");
    filt = "."+one+"."+two+"."+three;
    $("#myTable tr").hide();
    $(filt).show();
    $("#thead").show(); 
    alert(filt);
 }
</script>
```

Test in link https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/kbkkg4mc/

The code of OP had errors in html structure, the code html was broke because a tag has not correctly closed attr href.
jQuery was not included.
The functions javascript they filtered by a class. In the solution, filter works with all class(selects) and show all coincidence.

Comment: Add id 'thead' to row head and add $("#thead").show();   in a javascript, see a code again!

Comment: Please add both the reason the OP's code was wrong, and how your code fixes his problem so that this can be helpful to more people then just the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This use JQUERY => [Where do you include the jQuery library from? Google JSAPI? CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn)

here is the full one that work

```js
function jsUnitFilter() {
  // get the value of the selected link
  var reqGraad = $('#GraadFilter').val();
  var reqOnderwerp = $('#OnderwerpFilter').val();
  var reqSoort = $('#SoortFilter').val();

  // we hide everything
  $("#myTable").find('tr').hide();

  $("#myTable").find("tr." + reqGraad + "." + reqOnderwerp + "." + reqSoort).show();
  $("#myTable").find("tr:first-child").show();


  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myTable">

  <table>
    <tr>

      <td>Sorteer op soort:
        <br>
        <select size="1" id="SoortFilter" onchange="jsUnitFilter()">
          <option value="all-sc">Alles tonen</option>
          <option value="SC1">Opwarming</option>
          <option value="SC2">Oefening</option>
          <option value="SC4">Andere</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>Sorteer op onderwerp:
        <br>
        <select size="1" id="OnderwerpFilter" onchange="jsUnitFilter()">
          <option value="all-oc">Alles tonen</option>
          <option value="OC11">Voetenwerk algemeen</option>
          <option value="OC21">Tactiek dubbel</option>
          <option value="OC23">Wedstrijd analyse</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>Sorteer op graad:
        <br>
        <select size="1" id="GraadFilter" onchange="jsUnitFilter()">
          <option value="all-gc">Alles tonen</option>
          <option value="GC2">Gemakkelijk</option>
          <option value="GC3">Gemiddeld</option>
          <option value="GC4">Moeilijk</option>
          <option value="GC6">Variabel</option>
        </select>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>

</div>


<div class="myTable">
  <table id="myTable">

    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>
        <img src="check.png" width="20" height="20">
        <img src="wait.png" width="20" height="20">
      </td>
      <td>Soort</td>
      <td>Onderwerp</td>
      <td>Graad</td>
      <td>Benaming</td>
      <td>URL</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC1 OC11 GC6">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>
        <img src="check.png" width="20" height="20">
      </td>
      <td>Opwarming</td>
      <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
      <td>Variabel</td>
      <td>Agility oefeningen</td>
      <td><a target="_blank" href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67XP-AekUoA>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67XP-AekUoA</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC11 GC2">
         <td>8</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
         <td>Gemakkelijk</td>
         <td>Splitstep - fundamentals - Kyo groen</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NYVs9pQgGSZzhCQXg3dnFfYUE/edit?pref=2&pli=1>https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NYVs9pQgGSZzhCQXg3dnFfYUE/edit?pref=2&pli=1</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC11 GC3">
         <td>11</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Voetenwerk algemeen</td>
         <td>Gemiddeld</td>
         <td>Vertrek vanuit de basis</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNgt6P_RDLc>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNgt6P_RDLc</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC2 OC21 GC4">
         <td>23</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Oefening</td>
         <td>Tactiek dubbel</td>
         <td>Moeilijk</td>
         <td>Lee Bok - Positiespel dubbel</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMYbU08AOaw&feature=youtu.be>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMYbU08AOaw&feature=youtu.be</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC4 OC23 GC6">
         <td>14</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Andere</td>
         <td>Wedstrijd analyse</td>
         <td>Variabel</td>
         <td>Londen 2012 - Heren dubbel - halve finale</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKj4S9ig7c8>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKj4S9ig7c8</td>
         </tr>

         <tr class="all-sc all-oc all-gc SC4 OC23 GC6">
         <td>15</td>
         <td><img src="check.png" width="20" height="20"></td>
         <td>Andere</td>
         <td>Wedstrijd analyse</td>
         <td>Variabel</td>
         <td>Londen 2012 - Heren enkel - finale</td>
         <td><a target="_blank"  href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytjD4f_I0sc>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytjD4f_I0sc</td>
         </tr>


</table>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the connection to the class names??

Comment: my version use a `hidden` CSS class, if you don't have it, it'll fail. I filter with the class I've add on `<tr>` line

Comment: so part of the code you posted is missing??    isn't there anything simpler to use for a filter

Comment: @ThomasDutoit just `.hidden { display: none;}` in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake. you should use `$(document).ready()`.
I've solved your problem just by using `ready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SoortFilter').change(function () {
        $(".all-sc").hide();
            $("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: i tried that but its not changing anything,  doesn't function at all

Comment: do i have to use <script type="text/javascript">
   or <script language="javascript">

Comment: @ThomasDutoit 
but it worked for me. do you want to show you on jsfiddle?

Comment: @ThomasDutoit hey Thomas, check it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/linkers/t5dxvwe7/2/
you should include jquery library, did you?

Comment: i did not, i never learned jquery        but it's getting close.

now the situation is like this: i put on a filter 'Soort'    the filter gets active,   but when i select a second filter it pushes the first one away

and how can i put this all together in one page

Comment: @ThomasDutoit don't worry. these are your first steps :D
I want you to ask another question about it to be solved better.

Comment: @MahdiGhandi no, it's the same question, and that's why the OP method is not good, and why mine seem so complex

Comment: How can i all make this in javascript (not jquery)  because everything in the table and options are loaded from an PHP echo that gets data from MSSQL

The problem is it has to be simple but effective and in my opinion, jquery ain't easy xd

Comment: isn't there any system like   GetelementsbyCLASS and   Style: Display=Inline or none

Comment: @ThomasDutoit jQuery is completely easier than pure javascript.

Comment: @MahdiGhandi ok, I've updated my answer, take a look, you'll understand what I mean by "no the good way to do it" ;)