# Do I have to download jQuery on the server if I use jQuery CDN?

Tags: jquery, cdn

Do I have to download the jQuery file from jQuery and put it on my server if I use the Google CDN code in my header? Is it one or the other?

Also, I know that jQuery gets updated. When jQuery gets updated, do I have to go to my older webpages and update the code, or just focus on adding the updated code to new webpages?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about jQuery updates. I don't know how often they happen but unless it's a huge update, all the functionality you could ever want is already there.

Comment: See: [Where do you include the jQuery library from? Google JSAPI? CDN?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/547384)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need both.  The CDN is a link to the code and serves the same purpose as downloading the file to your server and using a local link.  If you use the CDN, the drawback is response time.  In many cases, it's faster to load a local file than a CDN.

If you want to use a newer version, you'll need to change your CDN link or your local file.  However, you should test before changing JQuery version in production to ensure nothing breaks.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that Devlin. The only question I have left is:do I have to use a newer version of Jquery on my pages if an update is available?

Comment: No.  You only need to upgrade when there's a new feature released that you need to use.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.